# Configure SharePoint 2010 UPS with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ups

SOLUTION FOUND: For anyone else that happens to come across this problem, have a look-see at this: http://www.harbar.net/archive/2010/10/30/avoiding-the-default-schema-issue-when-creating-the-user-profile.aspx

TL;DR When you create UPS through CA, it creates a dbo user and schema on the SQL server using the farm account, however when doing it through powershell it creates it with a schema and user named after the farm account, but still tries to manage SQL using the dbo schema, which of course fails terribly.

NOTE: I've only included the parts of my script I believe to be relevant. I can provide other parts as needed.

I'm at my wit's end on this one. Everything seems to work fine, except the UPS Synchronization service is stuck on "Starting", and I've left it over 12 hours.

It works fine when it's set up through the GUI, but I'm trying to automate every step possible. While automating I'm trying to include every option available from the GUI so that it's present if it ever needs to be changed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$domain = "DOMAIN"
$fqdn = "fully.qualified.domain.name"
$admin_pass = "password"

New-SPManagedPath "personal" -WebApplication "http://portal.$($fqdn):9000/"
$upsPool = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name "SharePoint - UPS" -Account "$domain\spsvc"
$upsApp = New-SPProfileServiceApplication -Name "UPS" -ApplicationPool $upsPool -MySiteLocation "http://portal.$($fqdn):9000/" -MySiteManagedPath "personal" -ProfileDBName "UPS_ProfileDB" -ProfileSyncDBName "UPS_SyncDB" -SocialDBName "UPS_SocialDB" -SiteNamingConflictResolution "None"
New-SPProfileServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $upsApp -Name "UPS Proxy" -DefaultProxyGroup

$upsServ = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service"}
Start-SPServiceInstance $upsServ.Id

$upsSync = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Synchronization Service"}

$upsApp.SetSynchronizationMachine("Portal", $upsSync.Id, "$domain\spfarm", $admin_pass)
$upsApp.Update()

Start-SPServiceInstance $upsSync.Id
```

I've tried running each line one at a time by just copying it directly into the shell window after defining the variables, and none of them give an error, but there has to be something the CA GUI does that I'm missing.

Comment: check out the syntax highlighting, you need to balance your `""` at `-ProfileDBName "UPS_ProfileDB`

Comment: Whoops, my bad on the typo. I can't copy code directly due to isolation, so I had to type it over.

Comment: Check out [this sharepoint.SE question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57656/user-profile-sync-status-stuck-at-synchronizing) as there can be a number of reasons for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that happens to come across this problem, have a look-see at this: http://www.harbar.net/archive/2010/10/30/avoiding-the-default-schema-issue-when-creating-the-user-profile.aspx

TL;DR When you create UPS through CA, it creates a dbo user and schema on the SQL server using the farm account, however when doing it through powershell it creates it with a schema and user named after the farm account, but still tries to manage SQL using the dbo schema, which of course fails terribly.

The workaround is to put my code into its own script file, and then use Start-Process to run the script as the farm account (it's a lot cleaner than the Job method described in the linked article):

```
$credential = Get-Credential ("$domain\spfarm", $SecureString)

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-File C:\upsSync.ps1" -Credential $credential
```